# mysql innodb locking

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

In one transaction I'm inserting a lot of rows into table T1. 
"After insert" trigger of table T1 inserts into table T2.

Is it possible during that process select from T2 in another transaction? Or selecting from T2 waits after inserting to T1 is finished?

Comment: Probably not.  But there are details you have left out.  Can you provide the SQL that is being invoked, including any BEGIN/COMMITs and/or value of autocommit.  How many rows are being inserted?  By what means?  A single-row insert will be so fast that the question is irrelevant.

Comment: Because you are doing it all in 'one transaction', and the insert int T2 should be in te same transaction (think off what should happen on a ROLLBACK?).  Selecting from T2 has to do with [READ UNCOMMITED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html), but I did not have the need to search for that details 